# OS X 10.6 change folder Finder displays as Desktop?

Tags: macos, finder

I know this is weird, but is there a .plist or key that I can edit to make the Finder use a different folder besides ~/Desktop for its Desktop folder?

Why? Because I really like the BumpTop Desktop for Mac, but when I am not using it, I want my actual Finder Desktop to be of different contents. BumpTop only looks at ~/Desktop that I can tell.

Comment: I'm assuming that BumpTop gets this information from the Finder. It's likely that changing Finder's Desktop folder would end up changing BumpTop's folder as well.

Answer (score 1):

They share the same folder.

You could create another account to have separate folders or hiding the file on your Desktop so only BumpTop can see them, not the Finder.